# Composer package issue

Tags: composer-php

I work on a project that uses `composer` for dependency management:

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/annotations": "1.8.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.9.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.7.1",
    "doctrine/reflection": "1.2.0",
    "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "8.11.5",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.5.2",
    "james-heinrich/getid3": "v1.9.19",
    "php-extended/php-http-message-factory-psr17": "2.0.0",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "1.10.1",
    "psr/event-dispatcher": "1.0.0",
    "sabre/vobject": "4.2.2",
    "sabre/xml": "2.1.3",
    "spiral/roadrunner": "1.7.0",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/cache": "v4.4.4",
    "symfony/class-loader": "v3.4.38",
    "symfony/config": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/css-selector": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/debug": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/error-handler": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "v4.4.4",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/filesystem": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/finder": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/mailer": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/mime": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "1.14.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-idn": "1.14.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "1.14.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "1.14.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-php73": "1.14.0",
    "symfony/process": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/service-contracts": "2.0.1",
    "symfony/validator": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/var-exporter": "4.4.4",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.4"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add a new dependency to the project, namely `symfony/contracts`. This package replaces several other `Symfony` packages, among other the `symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts` package, which is indirectly required as a dependency in the project.

However, when running the `composer require symfony/contracts` command, I get an error message that I cannot figure out:

```
# composer require symfony/contracts:2.0.1
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v1.1.7|don't install symfony/contracts v2.0.1
    - don't install symfony/contracts v2.0.1|remove symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v1.1.7
    - don't install symfony/contracts v2.0.1|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v1.1.7
    - Installation request for symfony/contracts 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v2.0.1].
    - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (locked at v1.1.7) -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts[v1.1.7].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have tried removing everything except `composer.json` and doing a reinstall, but ended up with the same error.

Another puzzling issue was that the `symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts` package is not explicitly locked in `composer.json` to a certain version, yet the error message specifies the `v1.1.7` version, instead of the latest one, which is `2.0.1` as of this time. Looking into the `composer.lock` file, I see that there is a single `require` directive which includes this package, defined as `symfony/event-dispatcher` requires `"symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts": "^1.1"`. This indeed forces the `symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts` to version `1.1.7`, but I can't explain why it forces the package to be installed, instead of replacing it with `symfony/contracts`.

How can I add `symfony/contracts` to this project and remove the `symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts` dependecy (which is included in the `symfony/contracts` package).

Comment: Hello, in you composer.lock, which dependency require the `"symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts": "^1.1"`. It probably this dependency that break the update.

Comment: It is required by `symfony/event-dispatcher`. I've added this detail in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`symfony/contracts` **replaces** `symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts` and other packages. Check which of your other packages requires this package through `composer why symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts` - I would assume that you need to update any of your other packages before you can start using the unified contracts package.

In your current setup, `symfony/event-dispatcher` requires the specific contracts in v1.1. The package to be installed replaces these contracts, but only those from v2. Installing `symfony/contracts` with the version constraint `^1.1` might be the best solution, if you don't want to upgrade `symfony/event-dispatcher` to v5 - this relies on v2 of the contracts

Comment: The output of `why` command is: `symfony/event-dispatcher  v4.4.4  requires  symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (^1.1) `. I've updated the question with this bit of information.